# UITextField function not available in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I'm having a problem with applying a `textField` function in terms of a textView.

Previously, I was using a textField and the below code was running smoothly without any problem. Now, I decided to use a textView instead of a textField, so want to change every textField to a textView but don't know how to implement the `textField.addtarget()` function to a textView. What I want is, initially, when the textView is empty the button color isn't enabled but when there is text in it, the button color should be blue.

I can't find a proper function that contains a `#selector` to call my main function in the textView functions. I'd appreciate any help. Thank you very much in advance!

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    buttonColor.isEnabled = false    
    handleTextField()
}


func handleTextField() {

    textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
}   // used to call the main function



@objc func textFieldDidChange() {

if (textView.text != ""){
        buttonColor.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: UIControlState.normal)
        buttonColor.isEnabled = true
        return
    }
    buttonColor.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGray, for: UIControlState.normal)
    buttonColor.isEnabled = false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a delegate for it in `UITextViewDelegate` called [textViewDidChange(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1618599-textviewdidchange).

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        yourTextView.delegate = self
        print(locationName)   // not important
        buttonColor.isEnabled = false    // not important
    }

    //Your other code

    func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
        if (textView.text != ""){
            buttonColor.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: UIControlState.normal)
            buttonColor.isEnabled = true
            return
        }
        buttonColor.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGray, for: UIControlState.normal)
        buttonColor.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! This makes a lot of sense, but somehow didn't work for me. I edited the question. So in the textViewDidChange function I copied my  func textFieldDidChange() function but my button is always light gray now no matter what I enter. :-(

Comment: @Bobbydickson did you set the delegate to self?

Comment: I inserted self before every buttonColor..... in textViewDidChange but still not working unfortunately

Comment: @Bobbydickson check the edit. You need to set your text view delegate to self, so that the delegate method is actually called.

Comment: works like a charm now! thank you very much for spending your time!